# What does the notation <> mean ?

Tags: algorithm

```
k:=0; b:=1;  
{b=a^k}
```

`while k <> n do begin`

```
k:=k+1;   
b:=b*a;   
end;
```

Couldn't get help on it elsewhere .. hope to get it answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something I first saw in *VB.net*. It means "**Not equal to**".

The other formats you might see this notation as are:

```
!=
/=
=/=
^= (although in Java this is a bitwise XOR operation, in some notations ^ denotes not.)
```

Comment: so in other words it means k could be less than or greater than n?

Comment: That's true ... it is even common to write something like this in VB: string1 <> string2 ... VB is evil sometimes

Comment: Yeah exactly. It's like a re-phrasing.

Comment: @user2135813 If you are less than, or greater than, you can never be equal. That's whay `<>` means.

Comment: @das_weezul Don't get me started. The amount of operator overloading makes me die inside.

Comment: thanks all, appreciate your prompt replies.

Answer (score 2):

while k "is less than or greater than, hence not equal to" n